# Angular4 - Datepicker not working in ng build --prod

Tags: angular, npm, datepicker, angular-material2, production

I am working on a project which runs on Spring boot + Angular4.  I use  Angular material datepicker components (from official angular material site)

When  I run     `ng serve`  everything works fine I can select date and bind into  Date property without any problem.

But when I try production version  (using`ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod` ), my datepickers  dont work and it looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlQS0.png)

Console says ([full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bftFn.png))

```
`Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at new DateTimeFormat (native)`
```

My code:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput  (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()" (click)="dateTo.open()" [(ngModel)]="dateToValue" [mdDatepicker]="dateTo" placeholder="To">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="dateTo"></md-datepicker-toggle>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #dateTo ></md-datepicker>
```

My `app.module.ts`

```
import { MaterialModule, MdDialogModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
```

I use @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8. and @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.8.

I tried  to install newer versions (@2.0.0-beta.12) and change code following official GitHub site examples and breaking changes , but still the same.
I also tried it without ngModel property , run in   many browsers but nothing changed. I just cant understand why `--prod`  crashes my datepickers and works fine in  `ng serve`

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397481/aot-and-minification-failing-in-angular-4-with-external-modules

Comment: Thank  you for reply, but I think that is not solving my current problem , becasue I have no problem with  production build. It pass without any errror, but datepickers in running aplication  are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after many many hours  I found solution for my problem!

I installed the newest version of @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12  again  and all what has to be done  was insert these lines of code in your `MaterialComponents.module` (or your specific name) :

```
export class MaterialComponentsModule {
  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    dateAdapter.setLocale("sk-SK");
  }
 }
```

In my opinion  in development version  it was not necessary becasue of inserting some value by default, but in production version it didn't happend. Maybe it could be caused by using `ngx-translate` library without setting default language or something other.

But now , everything works as expected :)

Comment: @Michal Falat - I have the same problem. is your MaterialComponents.module is the file you created? I don't see that file in my entire project.